# Product to sum with three coeffiecients

Tags: trigonometry

Basically, I need to find the formula to convert equations like: sin * cos * sin to a sum with the same output. Just this but with 3 coefficients: [product to sum with 2 coefficients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4pRp.png)

Comment: Could please give us an explicit example of what you need?

Comment: Yeah sure, cos(A) * sin(B) * sin(C) but converted to a sum like how it was done in the picture I attached. (Or a different way if it's easier) just Product->Sum

Comment: $\cos(A)(\sin(B)\sin(C)) =\cos(A)(\cos(B-C)-\cos(B+C))/2= \cos(A)\cos(B-C)/2-\cos(A)\cos(B+C)/2$ then you apply $\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)$ formula.

Comment: Can you first expand $\cos A \sin B$ to a sum, then distribute $\sin C$, then lastly expand twice more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeatedly apply the formulas.

For example,

$\sin\alpha \cos\beta\sin\gamma  = (\sin \alpha \cos \beta) \sin \gamma = \frac{\sin(\alpha + \beta)\sin\gamma + \sin(\alpha - \beta)\sin \gamma}{2}$

You already know that

$\sin a \sin b = \frac{\cos(a-b) - \cos(a+b)}{2}$

Therefore

$\sin \alpha \cos\beta \sin \gamma = \frac{\cos(\alpha+\beta-\gamma) - \cos(\alpha+\beta+\gamma) - \cos(\alpha -\beta - \gamma) + \cos(\alpha - \beta + \gamma)}{4}$